# Inno Setup driver with dependencies

Tags: c++, windows, installation, driver, inno-setup

I need some help to make a Inno Installer, I want install drivers in the same time of my own project.
When the driver is just an "exe" file, it works fine :

```
[Files]
Source: ".\Component\Drivers\Driver1\driver1.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Check: Is64BitInstallMode;
[Codes]
ExtractTemporaryFile('driver1.exe');
Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\driver1.exe'), '-install "' + ExpandConstant('{tmp}') + '"', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
```

But when the driver is more complex with dependecies, it's not the same deal.
I have tried to put all files in the temp directory (yes this is ugly =)) and execute the driver but this solution doesn't work.

```
[Files]
Source: ".\Component\Drivers\Keithley Driver\*"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Check: Is64BitInstallMode;

[Code]
ExtractTemporaryFile('setup.exe');
Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\setup.exe'), '-install "' + ExpandConstant('{tmp}') + '"', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
```

Have you a good advice for me?
Can I compress the driver and all it dependencies in one "exe" file?
Thanx for your Help, Best Regards,
Clément.

**UPDATE 2 :**
This is my entir code :

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

#define MyAppName "App"
#define MyAppVersion "1.0"
#define MyAppPublisher "Other"
#define MyAppURL "http://www.other.fr"
#define MyAppExeName "App.exe"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={pf}\{#MyAppName}
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppName}
VersionInfoVersion={#MyAppVersion} 
AllowNoIcons=yes
OutputDir=.\Deployment
OutputBaseFilename=App-Setup
SetupIconFile=.\Component\App.ico
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
WizardImageFile=.\Component\App.bmp
WizardSmallImageFile=.\Component\App.bmp

[Languages]
Name: "en"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl";

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked
Name: "quicklaunchicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateQuickLaunchIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked; OnlyBelowVersion: 0,6.1

[Files]                             
Source: ".\Component\Cal\*"; DestDir: "{app}\Cal"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: ".\Component\Documentation\*"; DestDir: "{app}\Documentation"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: ".\Component\Softwares\Utility\*"; DestDir: "{app}\Utility"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: ".\Component\Softwares\System32\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: ".\Component\Softwares\App\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files
Source: ".\Component\Drivers\Keithley Driver\*"; Flags: deleteafterinstall createallsubdirs recursesubdirs; DestDir: "{tmp}";
Source: ".\Component\Drivers\Spec Driver\driver.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Check: Is64BitInstallMode;
Source: ".\Component\Drivers\Adaptater\adaptater.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Check: Is64BitInstallMode;

[Code]
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
ResultCode: Integer;
I: Integer;
begin
  // CurStep values
  // ssInstall, ssPostInstall, ssDone
  MsgBox('Hello.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then begin
    Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Keithley Driver\setup.exe'), '-install "' + ExpandConstant('{tmp}') + '"', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
    Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\driver.exe'), '-install "' + ExpandConstant('{tmp}') + '"', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);

    // Ask the user a Yes/No question
    if MsgBox('Do you need to use the Adaptater?', mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO) = IDYES then
    begin
      Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\adaptater.exe'), '-install "' + ExpandConstant('{tmp}') + '"', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
      MsgBox('Please, plug it now!', mbInformation, MB_OK);
      for I := 0 to 10 do
      begin
        Sleep(400);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,{#MyAppName}}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon
Name: "{userappdata}\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: quicklaunchicon
```

**UPDATE 3 :** 
This is my final [Code] part to install a driver with dependencies:

```
[Files]
Source: ".\Component\Drivers\*"; Flags: deleteafterinstall createallsubdirs recursesubdirs; DestDir: "{tmp}";

[Code]
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
ResultCode: Integer;
I: Integer;
begin
  // CurStep values
  // ssInstall, ssPostInstall, ssDone
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then begin
    Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Keithley Driver\setup.exe'), '-install "' + ExpandConstant('{tmp}') + '"', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
    Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Driver\driver.exe'), '-install "' + ExpandConstant('{tmp}') + '"', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);

    // Ask the user a Yes/No question
    if MsgBox('Do you need to use the Adaptater?', mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO) = IDYES then
    begin
      Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Adaptater\adaptater.exe'), '-install "' + ExpandConstant('{tmp}') + '"', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
      MsgBox('Please, plug it now!', mbInformation, MB_OK);
      for I := 0 to 10 do
      begin
        Sleep(400);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Thanx a lot Rik!

Comment: But you copy to TMP root loosing all subfolders - all files are in the main TMP dir, not in the subdirs as they are in the original folder. That may be the reason. Try to copy all with keeping the Directories layout (`Flags: createallsubdirs recursesubdirs`) E.g.: `Source: ".\Component\Drivers\Driver1\Keithley Driver\*"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: dontcopy createallsubdirs recursesubdirs; Check: Is64BitInstallMode;` Then try to `ExtractTemporaryFiles('*')` (all, with keeping Directories layout) e.g. in `function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;` or wherever you need.

Comment: If Rik's answer resolved your question, you should accept it [`this way`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/179541). You can also upvote it by clicking the up arrow beside the accept check mark. Now you have enough reputation to do so ;-) Thanks, and welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Thanx TLama, I have checked and upvoted his answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you are calling `ExtractTemporaryFile('setup.exe');` if its destination already was {tmp}.

I think this would be sufficient (note the wildcard in source and `deleteafterinstall`):

```
[Files]
Source: ".\Component\Drivers\Keithley Driver\*"; Flags: deleteafterinstall createallsubdirs recursesubdirs; DestDir: {tmp}

[Code]
Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\setup.exe'), '-install "' + ExpandConstant('{tmp}') + '"', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
```

I thought you would only use `ExtractTemporaryFile()` if you have a `dontcopy`-flag in the Source-line. Then that file will not be extracted and you can do it manually in code. Without a `dontcopy`-flag you don't need it.

Also your `[code]` segment is not complete.

Here is a small example of a working .iss:

```
[Setup]
AppName=test
AppVerName=test
DefaultDirName=C:\TEMP
OutputBaseFilename=test
OutputDir=C:\TEMP
Uninstallable=no
;PrivilegesRequired=none
PrivilegesRequired=admin
Compression=lzma/ultra
SolidCompression=yes

[Files]
Source: ".\Component\Drivers\Keithley Driver\*"; Flags: deleteafterinstall createallsubdirs recursesubdirs; DestDir: {tmp}

[Code]

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  // CurStep values
  // ssInstall, ssPostInstall, ssDone
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then begin
    MsgBox('Hello.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
    Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\setup.exe'), '-install "' + ExpandConstant('{tmp}') + '"', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
  end;
end;
```

Your files will **only** be in the {tmp} directory in ssPostInstall phase (and **not** in ssInstall phase).

Comment: hi RobeN & Rik, I have modified the [Files] part like you sayd.
But for the [Code] part, ExtractTemporaryFiles('*') doesn't work and I really need to use "ExtractTemporaryFiles" else nothing is extract in the tempory directory. I have tried to extract like that : "ExtractTemporaryFile('.\Component\Drivers\Keithley Driver\*');" but it doesn't work.

Comment: ExtractTemporaryFile does not work with directories. You need to investigate why the {tmp} directory does not contain the files. They **are** deleted right after the setup. So perhaps they where there. `deleteafterinstall` is just for show because i think InnoSetup deletes the whole {tmp} anyway (but it's good practive to use it).

Comment: Could you put a `MsgBox('Hello.', mbInformation, MB_OK);` above the Exec line and look in the %temp% dir if there is a subdir from innosetup which has the files?

Comment: Also your `[code]` is not complete because you should have begin and end tags, procedures when the code gets executed etc... BTW you can also use the `[run] tag to run a file during setup.

Comment: I edited my answer to include a small example. You code-segment needs to have a procedure CurStepChanged and you will only have your files in {tmp} during ssPostInstall phase. `[run]` is also executed after the ssPostInstall phase so you could use that.

Comment: I have change my first post with the entire [Code] section. I have verified with Message Box before and after the Exec but files are never copied in Temp.

Comment: That is because `PrepareToInstall` is at a stage where these files are not yet extracted to {tmp}. You'll need to extract all the files yourself (including the subdirectory ones) or you execute this (like my example) in `CurStepChanged` in a `if CurStep = ssPostInstall` statement (that's when they **are** extracted in {tmp}).

Comment: If you want to keep using `PrepareToInstall` you could look at [ExtractTemporaryFiles](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_extracttemporaryfile) (only in 5.5.3+) to extract **multiple** files at once. Then you could use wildcards. I don't know if subdirectories are extracted. (you can try). In this case don't forget to include `dontcopy` flag in the files because it is not necessary to extract them again in a later phase by Inno Setup.

Comment: I have found a solution but it's a little bit ugly. I copy the Keithley Driver in {app}, I launch the exe in [Run] and I delete the folder in [InstallDelete]. I'm not very proud of it, I gonna search a better solution...

Comment: Does Inno Setup not enter the begin of the complete function or just the `if ssPostInstall` part. If the latter then we need your complete .iss to check why there is no ssPostInstall phase. It could be you have something in your [setup] which prevents this part.

Comment: I also tested `ExtractTemporaryFiles('*');` (note the **s** in Files) in the `PrepareToInstall` you have and it **does** extract all files including subdirectories. (Just need latest version 5.5.3 of Inno Setup)

Comment: If you move the `MsgBox` inside the `if CurStep = ssPostInstall` and you get a "hello" during install you look in `%temp%` and search the latest 2 `is-xxx.tmp` directories and you look inside you'll see your files. They **can** be in subdirectories so you'll need to check the exact path within {tmp}\is-xxx.tmp\ to execute to make sure.

Comment: Inno enter only one time in the "if CurStep = ssPostInstall" condition, but it doesn't execute the Exec.
I'm going to try "ExtractTemporaryFiles".

Comment: In the temp folder, Keithley driver is extracted but not "driver.exe" and "adaptater.exe".

Comment: What did you use as parameter in `ExtractTemporaryFiles()`? Either `Is64BitInstallMode` is false or you use `Keithley Driver\*` to extract them and `driver.exe` is in the `root` directory. Perhaps you can use `.\Component\Drivers\*` at Files and use `ExtractTemporaryFiles('Drivers\*')`. You'll lose the `Is64BitInstallMode` but perhaps that does not matter.

Comment: Oops, you're using `.\Component\Drivers\Keithley Driver\*` so when extracting them they are all in the root of {tmp}. So your `{tmp}\Keithley Driver\setup.exe` does not work. You should use `{tmp}\setup.exe` or use my mentioned `.\Component\Drivers\*` in Source. You can use your `ExtractTemporaryFiles` or my `if CurStep = ssPostInstall`. Just make sure to execute with the right path.

Comment: I have put in update 3 my final script, all driver are copied in %temp% and they are installed at the end. I have a last problem, when I pass in "if CurStep = ssPostInstall then begin", Inno execute "Keithley Driver\setup.exe" and  "Driver\driver.exe" at the same time...

Comment: Then somehow the `ewWaitUntilTerminated` is not working. Perhaps the `Keithley Driver\setup.exe` spawns a separate install process and just returns to Inno Setup as being done.

Comment: Yes, I have tried with "If Exec() then", but it doesn't work so I have put the Keithley driver at the end and it's done!
Thanx a lot for you help Rick.
Best Regards,
Clément.